# Quartz 1.8 to 2.x Migration

Tags: java, scheduler, jobs, quartz

The following Code is written Quartz 1.8:

```
SimpleTrigger safeHashChainStateTrigger = new SimpleTrigger(
    SafeHashChainState.class.getName() + "Trigger",
    StampingServerInfo.QUARTZSERVICEGROUP, 
    new Date(TriggerUtils.getNextGivenSecondDate(null, 10).getTime()),
    null, SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY, 
    providerObj.checkIntProperties("stamping.restart.quartz.safeHashChainState.Timeout", 30, 5) * 1000);
```

I would like to migrate to Quartz 2.x, but the method `getNextGivenSecondDate` does not appear to exist any longer. How do I work around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [migration guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide.html) you could read this:

> "Methods on TriggerUtils related to construction of Date instances have been moved to DateBuilder and can be made easy use of via static imports. Dates can then easily and cleanly be constructed and used in-line with the new trigger builder DSL."

The *nextGivenMinuteDate* is in this link [nextGivenMinuteDate](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/DateBuilder.html#nextGivenMinuteDate(java.util.Date,%20int)).

Hope this helps.